# Warum verwendet man nicht die Substantivierung der Sprachen, wenn ein Adjektiv vor ihnen steht?

Tags: nominalization

Warum sagt man "im vereinfachten Chinesisch..." aber auch "im Deutschen..." oder "im Chinesischen..."?

Es gibt natürlich einen Unterschied zwischen substantivierten Adjektiven und Substantiven, bei Sprachen auch. Betrachtet folgende Beispiele:

- im vereinfachten Chinesisch
- im Deutschen gibt es kein Wort für ___
- Deutsch klingt komisch
- dein Deutsch ist sehr gut

Ich hätte gedacht, dass "Chinesisch" "Chinesischen" im ersten Satz sein solle. Obwohl ich jetzt weiß dass "Chinesischen" falsch ist, verstehe ich nicht wieso. Im zweiten Satz verwendet man die Substantivierung vom Adjektiv "deutsch", wie in folgendem Beispiel: "ich übersetze etwas ins Deutsche". Ich sehe keinen Unterschied zwischen den ersten zwei Sätzen, bis auf das Adjektiv vor "Chinesisch", was, glaube ich, keinen Unterschied machen sollte. Ich glaube, dass die Antwort im Unterschied zwischen "das Deutsche" und "das Deutsch" liegen muss, aber ich bin mir auch nicht sicher.

Comment: Ich finde die Quelle nicht (daher kann ich keine Antwort verfassen). Mein Eindruck ist, dass diese eine Ausnahme für *Deutsch* ist. *Deutsch*, die Sprache, verhält sich als nominalisiertes Adjektiv, die Anderen als übliches Nomen. Daher bekommen diese unterschiedliche Endungen.

Comment: Wer sagt, dass *im vereinfachten Chinesischen* falsch ist? Ich als Deutscherstsprachler hätte zwar auch *im vereinfachten Chinesisch* gesagt, aber Sprech- und Schreibgewohnheiten konstituieren noch keine Schulbuchregel... Anders gesagt: Ja, *im vereinfachten Chinesisch* ist eine verbreitete Ausdrucksweise. Ich wäre aber nicht so sicher, dass die andere unzulässig ist.

Answer (score 1):

Der einzige Grund, der mir einfällt, ist die Vermeidung der doppelten Flexionsendung (sowohl an Adjektiv als auch Substantiv) aus Gründen der Sprachökonomie oder auch der Sprachästhetik.

Eine doppelte Flexionsendung hat man freilich auch bei zwei Adjektiven, aber dort kann man sie nicht vermeiden. Wenn man sie aber vermeiden kann, geht die Tendenz dahin, es auch zu tun.

Comment: Darf ich daraus schließen, dass Sie sich meiner Erwägung anschließen, dass *im vereinfachten Chinesischen* überhaupt nicht "falsch" oder "unzulässig" ist?

Comment: Ja, ich meine auch, dass das nicht falsch ist, aber ungebräuchlich.